# "Activating" animations via "button" on A-Frame

Tags: html, aframe

I am using A-Frame to create a VR experience.

I want a button to change an items speed but instead of affecting a "_target", it just affects the object that is the button.

The code with the error:

```
    `<a-box color="#FFFDB6" position="-2 2 -7"
            event-set__mouseenter="material.color: #FFFF14"
            event-set__mouseleave="material.color: #FFFDB6"
            animation__AlteraSlow="startEvents: click; _target: #anim; property: position; from: -10 4 -10; to: 12 4 -10; dur: 5000; loop: true; dir: alternate; easing: linear">
     </a-box>`
```

It seems like the target function isn't working.

I tried to check if the problem was the "inactive" _target code, and it was because it functioned the same without it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Share simple runnable code or it will be hard to help. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great. Best of luck

Comment: is it the 'native' animation component? Doesn't look like it has a [_target attribute](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v1.4.0/src/components/animation.js#L42)

Comment: Add animation__AlteraSlow to the object you want to animate, and give a custom name to its starting event. Then add click event listener to the button (a-box in this case). When button event happens, emit that custom event to the object you want to animate.